# Do we need atomic variables if they are protected by a lock?

Tags: c++, atomic

Hi I have a class that looks like this:

```
class A {
public:
    int GetVal() {
        AutoLock(m_lock);
        return val;
    }
private:
    int val; // do we have to use atomic<int> val here?
    SpinLock or Mutex or Semaphore m_lock;
};
```

The question is: do we have to use atomic when we already have a Lock to protect it? Or the atomic is absolutely redundant?

Comment: Yes, atomics are only relevant when you don't use locks. You don't need it, in fact it should not be an atomic, because these are slightly less efficient then non-atomics, and bring no advantage when you use locks.

Comment: There can be cases where writers need to modify multiple variables in a consistent way, but some readers only need to look at one of the shared variables on its own.  Making that shared variable `atomic` allows cheap read-only access that doesn't need to take the lock.  (And yes, that's even cheaper than a readers/writers lock; in that case reader threads would still contend for modifying the cache line holding the lock.)

Comment: (If you do that, make writes to it cheap by using `memory_order_release` not seq_cst, or even `memory_order_relaxed` if loads don't need to sync with it.)